# Best way to format a chart for any length of string without using excel

Tags: java, string

I am trying to create a chart for my names, but it doesn't align correctly if the name is too short or too long. I want to know if there is way I can align the names no matter the length of the string. Below is the align method I used

`public static final String FORMAT = "%s\t%s,%s\t%s%n";`

```
public static void print() {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        System.out.printf(FORMAT, name[i], last[i], first[i], formatName[i]);
```

output:

```
Nirvana Narayan Narayan,Nirvana Nirvana--Narayan
Kim Do  Do,Kim  Kim--Do
Kiri Wood   Wood,Kiri   Kiri--Wood
Quinn Hume  Hume,Quinn  Quinn--Hume
```

Comment: Use `.length`, take the maximum and print the missing spaces for shorter strings. In C you have `%n`, that gives you the number of characters printed so far, but I'm pretty sure Java does not have a similar format specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [described by KaeptnNemo in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383282/best-way-to-format-a-chart-for-any-length-of-string-without-using-excel#comment93642663_53383282):

> Use `.length`, take the maximum and print the missing spaces for shorter strings.

The easiest way to print missing spaces is to use the [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method with a format string using e.g. the `%-10s` format to print at least 10 characters, left-justified, filling with spaces as needed.

E.g. since the longest text for the first column is 23, a format string such as `"%-23s %s%n"` can be used. Now just write the code to build the format string automatically:

```
String[][] input = { { "Nirvana Narayan Narayan", "Nirvana Nirvana--Narayan" },
                     { "Kim Do  Do", "Kim  Kim--Do" },
                     { "Kiri Wood   Wood", "Kiri   Kiri--Wood" },
                     { "Quinn Hume  Hume", "Quinn  Quinn--Hume" } };

// Find column widths
int[] widths = new int[input[0].length];
for (String[] row : input)
    for (int i = 0; i < widths.length; i++)
        widths[i] = Math.max(widths[i], row[i].length());

// Build format string
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < widths.length - 1; i++)
    buf.append("%-").append(widths[i]).append("s ");
String fmt = buf.append("%s%n").toString();

// Print table
for (String[] row : input)
    System.out.printf(fmt, (Object[]) row);
```

*Output*

```
Nirvana Narayan Narayan Nirvana Nirvana--Narayan
Kim Do  Do              Kim  Kim--Do
Kiri Wood   Wood        Kiri   Kiri--Wood
Quinn Hume  Hume        Quinn  Quinn--Hume
```

---

If you like, you can even add column-separators.

```
// Build format string
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("|");
for (int i = 0; i < widths.length; i++)
    buf.append(" %-").append(widths[i]).append("s |");
String fmt = buf.append("%n").toString();
```

*Output*

```
| Nirvana Narayan Narayan | Nirvana Nirvana--Narayan |
| Kim Do  Do              | Kim  Kim--Do             |
| Kiri Wood   Wood        | Kiri   Kiri--Wood        |
| Quinn Hume  Hume        | Quinn  Quinn--Hume       |
```